# Standard Profile for community

Tags: community

Among the various Salesforce Standard Profiles, there exist the following Profile for Customer Community.
1.Customer Community user
2.Customer communitu login user
3.Authenticated Website user
4.High Volume customer  portal 
5.Customer Portal manager Standard 
6.Customer Portal manager custome

Can anyone tell me what is the purpose of those profile for customer community

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're asking about these profiles because they appear in a Dev Org. You'll learn more about them if you go into your Dev Org and examine the permissions associated with each of those profiles. That should better help you understand what each of those profiles is for and the default permissions assigned to them.

That having been said, most of these are associated with a particular license that an org will need to purchase in order to use certain features available in Salesforce. Most are better explained in [About Customer Portal User Management](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_manage_users.htm&language=en_US#CPprofiles) (lower down on the page) than I can possibly attempt to explain here; particularly since many of them don't especially apply directly to a Dev Org since you're not purchasing the license.

The High Volume Customer Portal can be used in a number of situations, however its also directly equivalent to a [Service Cloud Portal User License](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_servicecloudportal.htm&language=en_US) which I believe is the primary reason you see it in a Dev Org along with the fact that a Developer might need it available to support an app he's working on. That it can be used in so many different ways is something that makes licensing very confusing to understand at times.

One needs to examine the actual license they've purchased in their org to see exactly what it covers when cloning and assigning Users to it.